# lock and unlock cells based on another cell's value (excel 2013)

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-statements, excel-2013

Can someone please help me out. I've been reading about VBA scripting that allows for the unlocking of cells based on another cell's value, but I just can't seem to make it work with my spreadsheet or even with a blank spreadsheet.

Here is what I would like to do:

I have cell A1: A5 with a validation values of the following (a list) "Yes", "No", and "Select".

If A2 = "Yes" – I would like to see cell B2 = unlocked;

If A2 = "No" – I would like to see cell B2 = unlocked; and

If A2 = "Select" – I would like to see cell B2 = locked.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
If LCase(Range("A2:A10")) = "Yes" Then
    Range("B2:B10").Locked = False
ElseIf LCase(Range("A2:A10")) = "No" Then
    Range("B2:B10").Locked = False
ElseIf LCase(Range("A1:A10")) = "Select" Then
    Range("B2:B10").Locked = True
End If
End Sub
```

Ps. I read a few comments on Stackoverflow, but the info does not seem to work.

https://www.teachexcel.com/excel-help/excel-how-to.php?i=302178

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Remember that locked cells are only locked when the whole sheet is protected.

Comment: Better to include your actual code in your question, and describe what it does *instead* of working.

Comment: i am sorry about that, I just updated the question and added the VBA code.

Comment: If you use UCase in your equation you need to equate it to uppercase: `"YES"` , `"NO"`, and `"SELECT"`.

Comment: Why is your code using `A1:A10` in one spot and `A2:A10` in other spots, and `B1:B4`, `B1:B10` and `B2:B10` - are the different ranges deliberate or are they typos?  If deliberate, please expand the question to give the exact rules you want to use to determine whether a cell should be locked or not.

Comment: You cannot compare 9 cells at once to a single text string. `If UCase(Range("A2:A10")) = "Yes" Then` You have to loop through the cells. Further, your second criteria references 9 cells again but only attempts to action on 4.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. The script worked. For those of you that are new to VBA code and learning how to protect worksheets. When pasting/drafting VBA code, ensure that the cell you want to be locked or unlocked is by default "locked". What does this mean? Lock the cell under properties. Then as you are about to protect the spreadsheet, be sure to "deselect" the box that gives permission to select locked cells; and leave only the check box for unprotected. Just FYI.

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the cells in column A and perform an action on the cells in column B through an offset.

```
dim rng as range
with worksheets("sheet1")
    for each rng in .range("a2:a10")
        select case lcase(rng.value2)
            case "yes", "no"
                rng.offset(0, 1).locked = false
            case "select"
                rng.offset(0, 1).locked = true
            case else
                'do nothing if not yes, no or select
        end select
    next rng
end with
```